# Italian users: how do you translate "curve fitting"?

Tags: terminology, translation-request

I always write in English, but I came across this issue several times when discussing issues with my Italian peers. How do you translate the verb "to fit" when referring to fitting something (a curve, a surface, the parameters of a model, etc.) in Italian? I noticed many people end up saying "fittare", but this hurts my ears a bit. Is there a proper translation?

Comment: [Interpolare](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your linked Wikipedia article translates "curve fitting" to "curve fitting". It involves a bit more than interpolation and I would have thought *regolare* might be a possibility: French and Spanish might suggest something like *ajust-* but there is no j in Italian

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I did a short course at school  (I also did Latin)   My French and Spanish are better so I can get by in Italy when on holiday a few times.

Comment: "to fit" is *adattare*, but I'm not sure that it is the "standard" Italian mathematical term.